# Implement Iterable where hasNext depends on mutable object state, which is mutated through explicit call

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-11

I am trying to implement Iterable interface on an object, where hasNext method on iterator will depend on mutable object state, this state is mutated by explicit function call after call to each next.
Basically I am doing such implementation to keep it consistent across multiple implementation.-

1. First implementation is external API base implementation, paginated API returns a token to determine if more pages are pending to be fetched.
2. Second implementation is, where we have a Collection of Object, and we have to make API call for each object in Collection
   Is such implementation is flawed, what I can do to improve this implementation-

```
public class MutableObject implements Iterable<MutableObject> {
    String personId;
    boolean initialCall;
    String tokenId;

    public MutableObject(String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.initialCall = true;
    }

    public MutableObject(String personId, boolean initialCall, String tokenId) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.initialCall = initialCall;
        this.tokenId = tokenId;
    }

    public void updateState(String tokenId) {
        this.initialCall = false;
        this.tokenId = tokenId;
    }

    private MutableObject currentState() {
        return this;
    }

    private class MutableObjectIterator implements Iterator<MutableObject> {

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return initialCall || Objects.nonNull(tokenId);
        }

        @Override
        public MutableObject next() {
            if(!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements");
            }
            return currentState();
        }
    }
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Iterator<MutableObject> iterator() {
        return new MutableObjectIterator();
    }
```

and it can be called like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MutableObject mutableObject = new 
            MutableObject(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        int count = 0;
        String prevToken = null;
        Iterator<MutableObject> itr = mutableObject.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            MutableObject currState = itr.next();
            System.out.printf("[%d]: Curr State: %s\n", count, 
                currState.toString());
            if(++count < 5) {
                prevToken = "DUMMY_TOKEN";
            } else {
                prevToken = null;
            }
            currState.updateState(prevToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is already working code, the place to ask about improving it is at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This is proposed solution, I was looking around suggestion, if its right design approach

Comment: What is this iterator iterating over? `currentState()` returns `this` so iterating over an instance of `MutableObject` will yield the same instance over and over again. For example, `for(MutableObject o: new MutableObject("blah")) {}` will produce an infinite loop. There’s no sense in implementing `Iterable` and violating everything programmers would expect from an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

In my view code looks fine. However, what I would replace is the following line:

```
Objects.nonNull(tokenId)
```

by:

```
tokenId != null
```

Why? Because is it simpler to read.